# Detecting the right View

Tags: android

I need a little bit help, defining my in event_filter.xml declared Views. 
It is an child of an AbstractDetailListFragment and implements a DatePicker and a Spinner item.
But I dont know how to acces them in an AbstractDetailFragment.
By defining

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View theView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    ImageButton searchEnterButton = (ImageButton)getNavigationFragment().getNavigationBar().getRightButton();
    View view = getView();
    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) container.findViewById(R.id.datePickerEvent);
    Spinner inSpinner = (Spinner) container.findViewById(R.id.category_list);
    spinner = inSpinner;
    downloadCategories();
```

the variables view, datePicker, inSpinner always are null!

Any Ideas?
thanks a lot.

Comment: So show us event_filter.xml and the onCreateView() of AbstractDetailFragment.

Answer (score 0):

That's a thing about fragments. I've been looking for the same error for days, until I read a little bit about fragments (i was lazy and i recommend you not to follow my footsteps ). The way i solved it was by overriding onViewCreated and "catching" views there:

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    View rootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container,
                false);
        return rootView;

    }

//and you use rootView to call findViewById
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button myButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        sendFeedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    }
```

}